# Reading .dat file and including whitespace

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .dat file containing text which I would ultimately like to end up converting to a pandas DF. I am having an issue loading the 'blank words' in this file. Ultimately I would like it to be something like:

```
A    b    C    D    E
1    2         4    5
2    7    r    6    s
g         j    l    4
```

Right now I have tried

```
contents = [i.strip().split() for i in open(file).readlines()]
```

This returns lists of various sizes. In the case of the example I gave above, it would be, list1 =  size4, list2 = size5, list3 = size 4. As you can see, the blank row information is not included.

I also tried:

```
 content = open(file).read().split()
```

this returns a large list of all words and ignores the blanks. Any thoughts on this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converted .dat file to CSV, loaded using Pandas CSV function with ISO-8859-1 encoding instead of UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, use [`pandas.read_fwf`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html):

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""A    b    C    D    E
1    2         4    5
2    7    r    6    s
g         j    l    4"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_fwf(pd.compat.StringIO(temp))
print (df)
   A    b    C  D  E
0  1  2.0  NaN  4  5
1  2  7.0    r  6  s
2  g  NaN    j  l  4
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately the problem is not converting the file into the pandas DF, the problem is loading the file including the white space data such as you shown in your 'temp' example.

Comment: Actually manage to open it in the correct format as your example with a simple with open(file) as f, however the read_fwf returned a very strange dataframe

Comment: @Ciaran O Brien Are data confidental? If not, can you send me file to my email in my profile?

Comment: Thank you for the help. In the end I decided to convert the .dat file to CSV, open it using ISO-8859-1 encoding and pandas CSV read function, which was a workaround.